# Is document.getElementById being fetched as a string?

Tags: javascript, string, innerhtml

Can someone tell me if document.getElementById fetches the element as a string?  I am creating a variable with this and then attempting to compare it to some ranges and it's not working.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue3);
function queryValue3 () {
var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B2:B17&key=0Ai_2YLvaQba0dFlQQnU2ZWV1SFp2QUZMcHVfcnVQcFE&gid=10');
query3.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query3: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
var data3 = response.getDataTable();
var m1 = data3.getValue(0, 0);
var red22 = "<span style='color:#ff0000'>" + a22 + "</span>";
var yellow22 = "<span style='color:#FF9900'>" + a22 + "</span>";
var green22 = "<span style='color:#009900'>" + a22 + "</span>";
if (m1 <= 70)
{
m1 = green22;
}
else if (71 === m1 && m1 <= 89)
{
m1 = yellow22;
}
else if (m1 >=90)
{
m1 = red22;
}
console.log ("m1= " +m1)
document.getElementById('m1').innerHTML = m1;
console.log ("m1= "+m1)
});
}
```

Thanks...

Edit 3/24/2014 - Shortly after the exchanges in this post I got this thing working to handle 16 metrics.  Last week I threw it up on GitHub.  You'll find the [code here](https://github.com/davelalande/Business_Intelligence_Dashboard/blob/master/cms_dashboard.html).  Hopefully this will help others wanting to use Google Spreadsheets as a data source for web gauges.

Comment: "This is not working" is not an in-depth analysis of the outcome of your many hours of debugging. Please present your actual findings.

Comment: What is `m1`? your assigning it to a number of variables, but i dont see it being defined anywhere.

Comment: What do you expect the last line to do?

Comment: @bažmegakapa I'm trying to change the initial element which is a number coming from a Google Sheet to create some code I can use in my HTML to change a label color dynamically to match the gauge range color.  I'm trying to compare m1 to one of three ranges where they match the ranges in the gauge.  I went ahead and included the entire function so you can see where I'm getting m1 from.

Answer (score 5):

The `getElementById` method returns a reference to a DOM object, not a string.

However, I don't think that's your problem. In the comparisons you are attempting to use a `=<` operator, which doesn't exist.

Also, you are doing some confusing things in your code. You are creating the strings `red22`, `yellow22` and `green22`, then replacing one of them with the value from `m1`, which you haven't defined here. Then you are getting the `innerHTML` from an element with the id `m1`, but you don't do anything with it. It seems that you want to use the strings and the element together somehow, but then you do it all backwards.

Comment: +1 for noticing the nonexistant operator.

Comment: @DaveLalande: Now you are putting a value in an element with the id `m1`, then it seems like you are trying to use the variable `m1` as if it contained the value that you put in the element.

Comment: @Guffa I think I see what you're saying.  I am using the wrong method to try to fetch the value of the cell in the Google sheet in the first place?

Comment: @DaveLalande: That part looks all right, but you are putting the value in an element, not a variable. Also, you are missing an `if` after each `else`.

Comment: @Guffa I think I corrected the creation of the m1 variable and added the if after else.  I see how that changes the logic of my comparison of m1.  According to the JavaScript console in Chrome it makes it to the end of the function and Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token}

Comment: @DaveLalande: You have an extra `}` before the `});`. I think that you want `document.getElementById('m1').innerHTML = m1;` there at the end, to put the value in the element.

Comment: @Guffa This thing makes it all the way to console.log ("m1= " +m1)
document.getElementById('m1').innerHTML = m1;
console.log ("m1= "+m1) and comes up with an error in the console of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null  You can see all the source here.  http://landash.com/samples/panel_with_color_labels.html

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById)), it will return the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element), or `null` if nothing exists with that ID.

However you're calling `.innerHTML` which returns a string. Is that the source of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The method [`document.getElementById()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) returns a DOM [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614), not a string.

Click on the links above they bring you to the W3C Recommendation.

Here is what MDN has to say about it: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element

Basically you will get an underlying native DOM Object defined by the Browser itself. What that 'native DOM Object' does and which interface it implements, depends from case to case and has to be looked up for example at W3C or at MDN.

Comment: `getElementById` returns an element or `null` if no matching element is found. ;-)